# Custom DateTime day length

Tags: c#

I have a control where you can drag elements into a `Gantt` like `timetable`. The lowest time in the day is `8 a.m` while the highest time is `4 p.m`. Is there an elegant way, that I could tell the `DateTime` structure to take this time interval instead the `24 hour one`?

Comment: Isn't `TimeSpan` struct used for time spans?

Comment: Yes. But that is not the point. If I add 8 hours to a `DateTime` it should have the same effect as adding 1 day

Comment: i think what he wants to do is to do timecalculation on a structure based on a day starting at 8 and ending at 16 (and probably taking out the weekends too) and ask questions like earliest start time is XXX task has 30 hours of work ... when is ist done?

Comment: @Andro workdays aren't 8 hours long. You need to create *your own* calendar classes and time calculation logic. It's no accident that project management applications support multiple calendars with changing work hours, holidays etc

Comment: You could do something fancy with the field, by if time > 4pm + 16 hours.

Comment: As the question currently stands, I don't know whether to answer with a simple "no" or to flag as "too broad" - can you elaborate a bit more what you're trying to achieve? For instance, is the drag-drop ability relevant to the data type?

Comment: @Andro this is a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X (implement time management logic) and think that Y is the solution (change how the DateTime classes themselves behave). Inevitably you run into problems, because you are trying to use one class to do something completely different. Instead of asking about X though (time management), you ask about Y (DateTime).

Answer (score 0):

You surely can not change the behavior of DateTime's existing methods but Extension methods would come handy here.

As per your requirement you want the date to move forward 24 hours if you add 8 hours to the current date. (Correct me if my understanding is not right).

You can create Extension method with then AddWorkHours (or may be something more appropriate suiting your naming conventions) which will take number of hours as input (such as 8) but actually add 24 hours to the current date.

The code would look something like as following.

```
public class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime AddWorkHours(this DateTime dateTime, int workHours)
    {
        var workHoursPerday = 8; //Here 8 also can be configurable value if you have different working hours for different customer.
        var daysToAdd = (int) workHours/workHoursPerday; //You can have validation here to check if workHours are in exact multiplex of 8. 
        //Also you can have rounding off logic.
        dateTime.AddDays(daysToAdd);
    }
}
```

You just need to make sure of calling correct method in your call at proper places.
I hope this would at least give some idea to solve your problem.

Comment: It's a nice attempt but I don't see any problem that this code fixes

Comment: This is a generic logic. You can always customize the logic as per your business requirements. Checking for the day of the week would and change number of days to add would solve weekend issue too.

Comment: True... it does not solve this specific problem but author can use it as a hint and customize it to fit the needs.